How do I update the value of a variable with each iteration
int main() 
{
    int n=50,k,l,A;
    char ok;
    
    printf("Is the number guessed %d?",n);
    scanf(" %c",&ok);
    
    for(int i=0; i<60; i++) {

        if(i==0) {
            k=n+(n/2);
            l=n-(n/2);
            n=n/2;
        }
    
        if(i>=1) {
            k=A+(n/2);
            l=A-(n/2);
            n=n/2;
        }
    
        if(ok==72) {
            printf("Is %d the number you guessed?",k);
            scanf(" %c",&ok);
            A=k;
        }
    
        if(ok==76) {
            printf("Is %d the number you guessed?",l);
            scanf(" %c",&ok);
            A=l;
        }
    
        if(ok==89) {
            printf("The number you guessed is found");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

In this I want A to update its value with each iteration but unfortunately it takes up a fixed value and operates on it. How do I make it update its value with each iteration?
I tried to improve it but it just comes back to repeating values and not getting updated with each run of a loop

By the 7th iteration of the loop (i == 6), n becomes 0.  Once that happens, k, l, and A will all be equal and will no longer change.

When (i>=1) the A is undefined, yet you are using its value


In this I want A to update its value with each iteration but unfortunately it takes up a fixed value and operates on it. How do I make it update its value with each iteration?

The problem is that you do n=n/2; in every iteration. It means that n will take these values:
n:
50 -> 25 -> 12 -> 6 -> 3 -> 1 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 ....

When n becomes 0 (actually already when it becomes 1) the variables l and k will no longer change and consequently A will no longer change.
In other words - your algorithm for finding the next guess is wrong.
That's obviously a major problem but besides that there are several other things in your code that should be changed. For instance, don't use numbers for characters.
Instead of your algorithm, I would suggest that you operate with a low limit and an upper limit. The guess is then the number in the middle between low and upper limit. Depending on the user input, you then change either low or upper limit.
Something like:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int n;
    int upper=100;
    int low=0;
    char ans;
    
    for(int i=0; i<60; i++) {
        n = (low + upper) / 2;
        
        printf("Is %d the number you guessed?\n",n);
        if (scanf(" %c", &ans) != 1) {
            puts("Input error");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(ans == 'H') {
            low = n + 1;
        }
    
        if(ans == 'L') {    // consider using "else if"
            upper = n - 1;
        }
    
        if(ans == 'Y') {    // consider using "else if"
            printf("The number you guessed is found");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Disclamer: I have not fully tested this algorithm so there may be some corner case where it fails. I'll leave a full test to OP.
